# create two alias of same label for different DB - composite databases

Tags: neo4j, cypher

is it possible to access data of same label name in two databases and different alias in composite database.
for example - label = person , which i have created in two different databases personDbPartition1 and personDbPartition2 respectively. i have separate alias also, see below commands:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE personDbPartition1 TOPOLOGY 3 PRIMARY;
CREATE DATABASE personDbPartition2 TOPOLOGY 3 PRIMARY;

CREATE COMPOSITE DATABASE socialDb;
CREATE ALIAS socialDb.personP1 FOR DATABASE personDbPartition1;
CREATE ALIAS socialDb.personP2 FOR DATABASE personDbPartition2;
```

1. personDbPartition1: i have created data in personDbPartition1 and relationships

```sql
CREATE (p:person {name: 'user10001', age: 30});
CREATE (p:person {name: 'user10002', age: 30});
CREATE (p:person {name: 'user10003', age: 30});
CREATE (p:person {name: 'user10004', age: 30});

CREATE CONSTRAINT for (p:person) REQUIRE p.name IS UNIQUE;

match(a:person{name: 'user10001'}),(b:person{name: 'user10002'}) create(a)-[:knows]->(b) return a,b;
match(a:person{name: 'user10002'}),(b:person{name: 'user10003'}) create(a)-[:knows]->(b) return a,b;
match(a:person{name: 'user10003'}),(b:person{name: 'user10004'}) create(a)-[:knows]->(b) return a,b;
```

2. personDbPartition2: i have created data in personDbPartition2 and relationships

```sql
CREATE (p:person {name: 'user10004'}); ## proxy data node
CREATE (p:person {name: 'user10005', age: 30});
CREATE (p:person {name: 'user10006', age: 30});
CREATE (p:person {name: 'user10007', age: 30});

CREATE CONSTRAINT for (p:person) REQUIRE p.name IS UNIQUE;

match(a:person{name: 'user10004'}),(b:person{name: 'user10005'}) create(a)-[:knows]->(b) return a,b;
match(a:person{name: 'user10005'}),(b:person{name: 'user10006'}) create(a)-[:knows]->(b) return a,b;
match(a:person{name: 'user10006'}),(b:person{name: 'user10007'}) create(a)-[:knows]->(b) return a,b;
```

all data created successfully and i can access them individually while login to specific database and through composite DB also

but when i am calling below combine cypher then its returning empty results:

```sql
CALL {
  USE socialDb.personP1 MATCH (p:person{name:'user10004'}) RETURN COLLECT(p.name) AS pids
}
WITH *
UNWIND [g IN graph.names() WHERE g STARTS WITH 'socialDb.personP2'] AS g
CALL {
  USE graph.byName(g)
  WITH pids
  UNWIND pids as pid
  MATCH (p:person{name:pid})-[:knows]->(c:person) RETURN p.name as pname, c.name AS cname
}
RETURN pname, cname
LIMIT 20;
```

am i missing anything in query? or same label not work for multiple database and alias ?

Answer (score 0):

The [graph.names()](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/graph/#functions-graph-names) function returns the aliases in **lowercase**, which is not documented (but should be).

So, change this line:

```
UNWIND [g IN graph.names() WHERE g STARTS WITH 'socialDb.personP2'] AS g
```

to this:

```
UNWIND [g IN graph.names() WHERE g STARTS WITH 'socialdb.personp2'] AS g
```

Comment: Thanks, its working after changing to lower case.